# Qual é a diferença de o using está dentro ou fora do namespace?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, namespace, using

Existe alguma diferença técnica concreta entre fazer isto:

```
using Biblioteca;
namespace Aplicacao {
    //código aqui
}
```

e isto?

```
namespace Biblioteca {
    using Aplicacao;
    //código aqui
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse especificamente não há, mas pode haver em alguns casos.

O `using` que podemos chamar como do arquivo todo tem menos prioridade que o `using` interno no código, então em alguns casos pode acontecer uma operação diferente. Isso ocorre quando tem ambiguidade de espaços de nomes entre o que está usando de forma direta e com o `using`. Vou dar um exemplo:

```
using Biblioteca;
namespace A.B {
    class X
         int x = Classe.Meth();
    }
}
```

Considere que existe isto também:

```
namespace A {
    class Classe {
         public int Meth() => 1;
    }
}
```

E

```
namespace Biblioteca {
    class Classe {
         public int Meth() => 2;
    }
}
```

Quanto você acha que `x` valerá?

Valerá 1 porque o `namespace` tem prioridade, então é a classe dele que será usado.

E agora colocando o `using` dentro:

```
namespace A.B {
    using Biblioteca;
    class X
         int x = Classe.Meth();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/InteriorUsing.cs).

E agora, quanto `x` vale?

Agora é 2 porque o `using` tem prioridade.

É uma situação quase em *corner case* e por isso não gosto de `namespace`s complicados, mas tem diferença. Ao mesmo tempo que usar `using` interno quase sempre só é necessário quando está complexo demais.